# How to determine Rasberry Pi board version using Arm Assembly/C?

Tags: c, assembly, arm, bare-metal

I'm in the process of developing a Test Kernel for Raspberry Pi devices. In doing so, I need to set-up the UART so we can write data to the device and be able to retrieve data that needs to be handled by the Kernel.  I want the test kernel to be able to run on multiple Raspberry Pi devices.  There is a slight issue though:

The UART addresses Differ between Versions. For example, the address for the RPi 1 line UART GPIO is:

```
0x20200000
```

But the address for the UART GPIO on RPi 2 and RPi 3 lines is:

```
0x3F200000
```

Naturally, this means that there would need to be two separate UART_INIT functions: 1 for RPi 1 line devices and 1 for RPi 2 and beyond.

Here is a sample of the UART handling code. This code is modified from code provided by osdev:

```
void uart_init_rpi1()
{
    // Disable UART0.
    mmio_write(PD_UART_INTERNAL_VALUES_RPI1->UART0_CR, 0x00000000);
    // Setup the GPIO pin 14 && 15.

    // Disable pull up/down for all GPIO pins & delay for 150 cycles.
    mmio_write(PD_GPPUD_RPI1, 0x00000000);
    delay(150);

    // Disable pull up/down for pin 14,15 & delay for 150 cycles.
    mmio_write(PD_GPPUDCLK0_RPI1, (1 << 14) | (1 << 15));
    delay(150);

    // Write 0 to GPPUDCLK0 to make it take effect.
    mmio_write(PD_GPPUDCLK0_RPI1, 0x00000000);

    // Clear pending interrupts.
    mmio_write(PD_UART_INTERNAL_VALUES_RPI1->UART0_ICR, 0x7FF);

    // Set integer & fractional part of baud rate.
    // Divider = UART_CLOCK/(16 * Baud)
    // Fraction part register = (Fractional part * 64) + 0.5
    // UART_CLOCK = 3000000; Baud = 115200.

    // Divider = 3000000 / (16 * 115200) = 1.627 = ~1.
    // Fractional part register = (.627 * 64) + 0.5 = 40.6 = ~40.
    mmio_write(PD_UART_INTERNAL_VALUES_RPI1->UART0_IBRD, 1);
    mmio_write(PD_UART_INTERNAL_VALUES_RPI1->UART0_FBRD, 40);

    // Enable FIFO & 8 bit data transmissio (1 stop bit, no parity).
    mmio_write(PD_UART_INTERNAL_VALUES_RPI1->UART0_LCRH, (1 << 4) | (1 << 5) | (1 << 6));

    // Mask all interrupts.
    mmio_write(PD_UART_INTERNAL_VALUES_RPI1->UART0_IMSC, (1 << 1) | (1 << 4) | (1 << 5) | (1 << 6) |
                       (1 << 7) | (1 << 8) | (1 << 9) | (1 << 10));

    // Enable UART0, receive & transfer part of UART.
    mmio_write(PD_UART_INTERNAL_VALUES_RPI1->UART0_CR, (1 << 0) | (1 << 8) | (1 << 9));
}
```

There is a secondary, similar function for handling the UART INIT on the RPi 2 and RPi 3 line. Having two separate UART INIT functions is fine,and not really the issue. The issue is being able to distinguish between board types. it'd save me a lot of hassle if there is a way to determine the current board in use. Not being able to, means that i need to make a separate test kernel for the RPi 1 Boards, the RPi 2-3 Boards, and any other RPi like boards, such as ODROID OC-2 for example. If somehow, there was a way to determine to the board type, i could use it as a condition and load the proper UART values on boot, meaning thatonly one singular kernel file is needed. One way that might work is testing based on the processor, which is unique between each RPi Revision and alternative boards. On x86 Platforms, you can use _RTDSC, but I'm fairly certain no such alternatives exist on NON-x86/x86-64 Processors.

So, the question I'm asking is: Is there a way, either in assembly or C that allows a way to check which type of board that the user/code is running on? Since I'm building an OS Kernel, I do not have access to non-compiler C libraries, so the C code would have to defer to volatile assembly instruction.

Comment: Then take a look at the existing linux kernel module responsible for creating this info. But I don't really understand how you are creating a portable kernel for the different versions, as the UART is really not the only and main difference. Different RPis have different CPUs

Comment: @inifinitelyManiac the user would be rthe person with the test kernel on the mSDHC. for example, i have a RPi 3b, but a friend of mine has an RPi 1. i was looking for a way that i would not have to recompile the test kernel for each board variation. I guess i should have been a bit more specific there.

Comment: @eugene sh. the Compiler in use is a generic target: gcc-arm-none-eabi. i'm well aware of the intrinsic differences between the boards, but all of them use Arm assembly.  The kernel executable is portable in that sense alone.

Comment: If the CPUs are different, you may test for that instead? Other (more robust and obvious IMO) way is to simply try to initialize the different UARTs so long, until one of them succeeds. From the source example it's not clear where that `0x20200000` is used, but doesn't some very first mmio_write fail if the UART is on different one? Or maybe if the writes fail just silently being ignored, there's some value which can be read back after write, so on invalid UART port it will be not modified and you can return that one as "fail"?

Comment: There is a 'mailbox' in the firmware that you can send request to get this information. [Read RPI board rev and mem size](http://raspberryalphaomega.org.uk/2013/01/13/how-to-read-raspberry-pi-board-revision-and-memory-size/) and also [U-boot source](http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=blob;f=board/raspberrypi/rpi/rpi.c;h=2146534b3653ca9b41b2f48cfb17aaa1ebaf3331;hb=HEAD) which is what Linux really delegates to do this in current Linux. (please upvote if useful so this is above other comments)

Comment: there is/are ARM cpuid registers you can read to distinguish the pi1, pi2, pi3 processors, from that you can tell whether it is 0x20xxxxxx or 0x3Fxxxxxx.

Answer (score 4):

Since each generation of pi uses a different cpu core from arm (a specific armv6 then an armv7 and then an armv8) you can easily detect them from a cpu id register.

```
.globl GETCPUID
GETCPUID:
    mrc p15,0,r0,c0,c0,0
    bx lr
```

The different cores return different values

```
PI3 0x410FD034
PI2 0x410FC075
PI1/Zero 0x410FB767
```

And from there you can set your peripheral base

```
if((id&0xFFFFFFFF)==0x410FB767) PBASE=0x20000000;
else                            PBASE=0x3F000000;
```

Answer (score 2):

ARM cores for RP1, RP2 and RP2 v1.2 (onwards) are different, viz. ARM11, Cortex-A7 and Cortex-A53.

But ARM CP15 has information regarding the architecture, part-number and revision of core, and as per ARM documentation, same instruction can fetch the details on both cores.

```
MRC p15,0,<Rd>,c0,c0,0; reads Main ID register
```

ARM11 would return part-number as 0xB76
Cortex-A7 would give 0xC07
and Cortex-A53 would give 0xD03.

Please see following two references from infocenter.arm (I could not add more that two links, so providing references to old and latest ones only)

**References:**
ARM1176JZF-S(PI-1):
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0301h/Bgbiddeb.html

Cortex-A53(PI-2 v1.2 onwards):    http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0500g/BABFEABI.html

Hope it helps.

[Thanks to old-timer for corrections]

Comment: pi2 and p3 are different cores, pi2 is an armv7 pi3 an armv8 (64 bit)

Comment: @old-timer thanks for your inputs. I have corrected the answer.

Comment: note the pizero is a shrunk down pi1 so it uses the same chip as the pi1 and same peripheral base address in the arm address space.